# ReadAll from File not working as Expected

Tags: go, gzip

I am trying to create a temporary gzip file and write to the file. The problem is that I am not understanding what is going on with ReadAll. I expected ReadAll to return the bytes written to the file... however there are none. Yet the File.Stat command shows that there is indeed data.

```
filename := "test"
file, err := ioutil.TempFile("", filename)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
defer func() {
    if err := os.Remove(file.Name()); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}()

w := gzip.NewWriter(file)
_, err = w.Write([]byte("hell0"))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

fileInfo, err := file.Stat()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println("SIZE1:", fileInfo.Size())
fmt.Println("SIZE2:", len(fileBytes))
```

Here is a playground link   https://play.golang.org/p/zX8TSCAbRL

Why are there no returned bytes?
How do I get the returned bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close the file before reading it.

From [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#Writer.Write) of gzip:

> Write writes a compressed form of p to the underlying io.Writer. The compressed bytes are not necessarily flushed until the Writer is closed.

The solution therefore is to `Close` both the gzip Writer as well as the underlying io.Writer before attempting to read the number of bytes.

```
    func main() {
        basename := "test"
        file, err := ioutil.TempFile("", basename)
        tempFilename := file.Name()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        defer func() {
            if err := os.Remove(file.Name()); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
        }()

        w := gzip.NewWriter(file)
        _, err = w.Write([]byte("hell0"))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        w.Close()
        file.Close()

        file, err = os.Open(tempFilename)
        fileInfo, err := file.Stat()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("SIZE1:", fileInfo.Size())
        fmt.Println("SIZE2:", len(fileBytes))

}
```

View on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eb_e96D439).

Answer (score 1):

Yo must [`seek`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek) the start of the file:

```
_, _ = file.Seek(0, 0)
fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Check the [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oF7EWI_j2J)